# Heroku Error: Invalid schema, expected `mongodb` or `mongodb+srv`

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

My app is able to connect to MongoDB locally but on heroku logs i'm getting this error:

Error: Invalid schema, expected `mongodb` or `mongodb+srv`

This is what my connection to mongodb looks like in my server.js file:

```
// // DB config
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

// // Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect(db)
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

config/keys:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  module.exports = require("./keys_prod");
} else {
  module.exports = require("./keys_dev");
}
```

keys_dev:

```
module.exports = {
  mongoURI:
    "mongodb://jenn123:jenn123@devconnect-shard-00-00-acrk4.mongodb.net:27017,devconnect-shard-00-01-acrk4.mongodb.net:27017,devconnect-shard-00-02-acrk4.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=devconnect-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true",
  secretOrKey: "secret"
};
```

keys_prod:

```
module.exports = {
  mongoURI: "process.env.MONGO_URI",
  secretOrKey: "process.env.SECRET_OR_KEY"
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're doing the production keys wrong.

process.env is an object containing the env variables as key and their values.
so instead of putting them in a string, you gotta remove the string and treat it as an object. like below:

```
module.exports = {
  mongoURI: process.env.MONGO_URI,
  secretOrKey: process.env.SECRET_OR_KEY
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is typically how I connect with mongoose.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();

let db = mongoose.connection;

mongoose.connect('your connection URL here', {
    auth: {
      user: "Your username",
      password: "Your password"
    }
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('connection successful')
    db = mongoose.connection;
    module.exports = db;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
  });
```

You can then use it in a file like so (this is assuming you've defined a job schema and are importing it):

```
const db = require('./db'); // provides the mongoDB connection
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
const Job = require('./schemas/jobs').Job


module.exports.createJob = function (newJob) {
    const job = new Job(newJob);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    job.save((err, data) => {
      if (err) {
          reject(err);
      } else {
          resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });
};
```